# Magento - Inventory filter with bands

Tags: magento, navigation, inventory, layered

I am trying to work out if I can code inventory into bands in layered navigation, like price. Searched and cannot see anyone that has tried this, Can anyone offer a pointer where to start?

Comment: please elaborate your problem definition.

Comment: Are you having the attribute called `bands`?

Comment: Magento prices when shown in layered naviagation are in 4 bands based on max and min price. I want to do this with inventory.